# Monitor 'popped' - beyond repair?

Tags: display

My two to three year old monitor suddenly made a *pop* noise, after which the screen went black immediately.  My computer still worked as I was able to navigate somewhat with keyboard shortcuts and listening to the sound effects. It would appear something in my monitor snapped.  It's out of warranty by now, so I bought a new monitor.  Still, I was wondering if this monitor can still be salvaged/saved somehow?  I have no idea how difficult it is to inspect the damage done to the monitor and if it's even worth it. It would be nice if I can fix it myself or fork over a small sum for repairs so I can dual screen.

The monitor is a flatscreen from *iiyama*. The model is **ProLite E2008HDS**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a CRT or a flatscreen monitor? Please [edit] your question with its model and all relevant details.

Comment: @BenN Model has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely you can fix it yourself and most components should be available from Digikey or Mouser.

You will of course need a multimeter, soldering iron, and a little skill.

Your first task is to disassemble the unit and take a look at the boards. Since you heard a "pop" you should be able to see some sort of physical damage somewhere on the boards. You can also do a *sniff* test and usually find the damaged component as well. Most likely the pop was either a capacitor or transistor.

If you do not want to tackle the repair yourself you could always find the faulty board and see if there is a replacement on eBay or Amazon, or find a local computer/tv repair shop and have them do it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise!  I did think it could be something with a capacitor when I was doing some research about it, but it was not advised to mess with it if people don't know what they're doing.  Some components are high voltage.  But there's a first time for everything...  I will purchase a nice pair of rubber gloves first. :)

Comment: Good idea on the rubber gloves. I've been shocked quite a few times and it doesn't feel good and could be potentially fatal. You typically have a hot side (AC) and cold side (DC) on your power board. 120v typically comes in and is converted to DC via a rectifier. Depending on the backlight system sometimes it is converted back to AC but at a much higher voltage (+200v) with decent current which *can* hurt you. Also be careful to dissipate large capacitors as they can hold a pretty heavy charge for a long period of time even after unplugging. You can discharge a cap by shorting the two legs.